# GroupBy on a field which has edge-n-gram analyzer creating all unnecessary ngram tokens as keys

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have created an Analyser (Lowercase + Stemmer + EdgeNgram) on a field called 'Name' (Text type). 
Search on that field is working fine.
I am facing an issue while trying an aggregation (group-by).
It is sending all the ngrams as keys in buckets. 
Suppose I am trying group-by query on Name field. It has 'ABCD' value.
On search, it is creating keys like A, AB, ABC, ABCD in the buckets which are unnecessary for the UI. I need only ABCD.
Please let me know if there is there any way to avoid that

search body:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_severity": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "severity"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_by_Name": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "Name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Field used for aggregation should be of type `keyword`. You can read more about it in [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

You will probably end up with creating [multifield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html) for the name field. One will be used for full-text search, other one for aggregations.

So for query you will use it as `f => f.Name` and for aggregation `f => f.Name.Suffix("keyword")`. Have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/property-inference.html).

Hope that helps.